# Why is it slow to access the same index twice in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hashtable

When using Pandas, it is slower to access the same row index twice than to get two different rows.

```
r = pd.Series(index=range(50000))
%timeit r.ix[[0,1]] #1000 loops, best of 3: 276 µs per loop
%timeit r.ix[[0,0]] #100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
```

The non-unique indexing case uses this slower function (as identified by `prun`):

```
{method 'get_indexer_non_unique' of 'pandas.index.IndexEngine' objects}
```

I understand if the index of the Series had non-unique elements we could no longer treat it as a hash table, and so would need to use this function. Why is this the case if the list of rows we're asking for has non-unique elements? I'm surprised Pandas even "knows" this.

Comment: Perhaps in the second case, pandas probably has to build a whole new data structure instead of simply a view of the larger dataframe